# is rmem_default size per socket or for entire stack?

Tags: linux, performance, sockets, networking

Does setting the `net.core.rmem_default` effect each socket or all sockets opened in the system?
What is the maximum value I can configure for the `net.core.rmem_default` parameter?

I understand it depends on RAM. Assume I have much RAM available.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`net.core.rmem_default` is the size of the incoming kernel socket buffer per one socket.

From [`man socket(7)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/socket.7.html):

> **SO_RCVBUF**
>
> Sets or gets the maximum socket receive buffer in bytes. The kernel doubles this value (to allow space for bookkeeping overhead) when it is set using `setsockopt`(2), and this doubled value is returned by `getsockopt`(2). The default value is set by the `/proc/sys/net/core/rmem_default` file, and the maximum allowed value is set by the `/proc/sys/net/core/rmem_max` file. The minimum (doubled) value for this option is 256.

Optimum incoming socket buffer size is [the bandwidth-delay product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bandwidth-delay_product).

In order to minimize `recv` syscalls your user-space socket buffer size should be not less than that of the kernel buffer. When using non-blocking I/O, having to issue more than one `recv` syscall to read the kernel socket buffer may result in starvation of other sockets.